# Transmission right click "Open Folder" opens xfburn instead of thunar

Tags: debian, bittorrent, mime-types, transmission, thunar

Regarding the Transmission bit torrent client, when I right-click the "Open Folder" option, the application xfburn opens instead of the file manager Thunar.

How can I fix this?

My operating system is Debian 10 Buster upgraded from Debian 9 Stretch where I also had the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Change MIME type using MIME Types Editor

I am using XFCE on Debian 10.

- Open System Settings
- Search for MIME
- Open MIME Type Editor

[image: MIME Type Editor]

- Look for relevant options which may be set to xfburn
- I found that `directory/inode` was set to `xfburn` instead of the default which is `File Manager`
- **Left** click on the application name (3rd col) and "set to default"

[image: Click here]

Solution found using info from

- https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3gj7vp/transmissiongtk_open_folder_opens_a_program/
- https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/mime